# Java initialization question

Tags: variables, initialization, local

```
JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,1));
ButtonGroup tubtype = new ButtonGroup();
JRadioButton roundrButton = new JRadioButton("Round", true);
tubtype.add(roundrButton);
JRadioButton ovalrButton = new JRadioButton("Oval", false);
tubtype.add(ovalrButton);
calcButton = new JButton("Calculate Volume");
exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
hlength = new JTextField(5);
hwidth = new JTextField(5);
hdepth = new JTextField(5);
hvolume = new JTextField(5);
lengthLabel = new JLabel("Enter the tub's length (ft):");
widthLabel = new JLabel("Enter the tub's width (ft):");
depthLabel = new JLabel("Enter the tub's depth (ft):");
volumeLabel = new JLabel("The tub's volume (ft^3):");
p2.add(roundrButton);
p2.add(ovalrButton);
p2.add(lengthLabel);
p2.add(hlength);
p2.add(widthLabel);
p2.add(hwidth);
p2.add(depthLabel);
p2.add(hdepth);
p2.add(volumeLabel);
p2.add(hvolume);
p2.add(calcButton);
p2.add(exitButton);
tab.addTab( "Hot Tubs", null, p2, " Panel #1" );

calcButtonHandler2 ihandler =new calcButtonHandler2();
calcButton.addActionListener(ihandler);
exitButtonHandler ghandler =new exitButtonHandler();
exitButton.addActionListener(ghandler);
FocusHandler hhandler =new FocusHandler();
hlength.addFocusListener(hhandler);
hwidth.addFocusListener(hhandler);
hdepth.addFocusListener(hhandler);
hvolume.addFocusListener(hhandler);

// add JTabbedPane to container
getContentPane().add( tab );
setSize( 550, 500 );
setVisible( true );
} 
public class calcButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
DecimalFormat num =new DecimalFormat(",###.##");
double sLength, sWidth, sdepth, Total;

sLength = Double.valueOf(plength.getText());

sWidth =Double.valueOf(pwidth.getText());

sdepth =Double.valueOf(pdepth.getText());

if(e.getSource() == pcalcButton) {
Total = sLength * sWidth * sdepth;
pvolume.setText(num.format(Total));
try{
String value=pvolume.getText();
File file = new File("output.txt");
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file,true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write("Length= "+sLength+", Width= "+sWidth+", Depth= "+sdepth+" so the volume of Swimming  Pool is "+value);
out.newLine();
out.close();
}
catch(Exception ex){}
}
}
}

public class calcButtonHandler2 implements ActionListener {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent g) {
DecimalFormat num =new DecimalFormat(",###.##");
double cLength, cWidth, cdepth, Total;

cLength = Double.valueOf(hlength.getText());

cWidth = Double.valueOf(hwidth.getText());

cdepth = Double.valueOf(hdepth.getText());

try
{
AbstractButton roundrButton;
if(roundrButton.isSelected())
{

Total = Math.PI * Math.pow(cLength / 2.0, 2) * cdepth;
}
else 
{
Total = Math.PI * Math.pow(cLength * cWidth, 2) * cdepth;
}
hvolume.setText(""+num.format(Total));
}

catch(Exception ex){}
}
}
}



class exitButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent g){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
class FocusHandler implements FocusListener {
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    }
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    }


public static void main( String args[] )
{
    Final tabs = new Final();
    tabs.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
}
```

I am getting an error that says my roundrButton may not have been initialized. Please help.

Comment: You'll want to include the entire class, or a minimal but complete class that exhibits the problem. The code you gave is unfortunately not particularly helpful in determining what your problem is: it does say where the problem is NOT, but that's not what you're interested in. A complete code sample and a paste of the compiler error will be extremely helpful in figuring out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is these lines here:

```
try
{
    AbstractButton roundrButton;
    if(roundrButton.isSelected())
    {
```

You're declaring a variable called `roundrButton`, and then attempting to call `.isSelected()` on it. You never assign anything to `roundButton`, though, so it is going to be `null`.

It seems like you might want to be referring to the `roundrButton` that you declared earlier. Have you considered making it a field of your class?

Comment: No, because I wasn't sure how to do that. I thought that if I called .isSelected that it would know what I wanted it to do...

Answer (score 0):

The error happens here:

```
try {
    AbstractButton roundrButton;
    if (roundrButton.isSelected()) {
```

You declared a variable called `roundrButton` but did not assign any object to it.

Then you called a method on, well, who knows?  There is no object on which to call the method, because the variable `roundrButton` never received a value.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is in method actionPerformed of class calcButtonHandler2 :

```
    try { 
AbstractButton roundrButton;
if(roundrButton.isSelected())
```

roundrButton is indeed not initialized and it will lead to a NullPointerException at runtime.