# Trouble with initialization

Tags: java, initialization, radio-button

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Final extends JFrame 
{
private JButton calcButton, exitButton;
private JButton pcalcButton, pexitButton;
private JTextField plength, pwidth, pdepth, pvolume;
private JTextField hlength, hwidth, hdepth, hvolume;
private JLabel lengthLabel, widthLabel, depthLabel, volumeLabel;
private JRadioButton roundrButton, ovalrButton;

public  Final()
{
super( "Final" );

JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
// constructing the first panel
JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));
pcalcButton = new JButton("Calculate Volume");
pexitButton = new JButton("Exit");
plength = new JTextField(5);
pwidth = new JTextField(5);
pdepth = new JTextField(5);
pvolume = new JTextField(5);
lengthLabel = new JLabel("Enter the pool's length (ft):");
widthLabel = new JLabel("Enter the pool's width (ft):");
depthLabel = new JLabel("Enter the pool's depth (ft):");
volumeLabel = new JLabel("The pool's volume (ft^3):");
p1.add(lengthLabel);
p1.add(plength);
p1.add(widthLabel);
p1.add(pwidth);
p1.add(depthLabel);
p1.add(pdepth);
p1.add(volumeLabel);
p1.add(pvolume);
p1.add(pcalcButton);
p1.add(pexitButton);
tab.addTab( "Pools", null, p1, " Panel #1" );

calcButtonHandler chandler =new calcButtonHandler();
pcalcButton.addActionListener(chandler);
exitButtonHandler ehandler =new exitButtonHandler();
pexitButton.addActionListener(ehandler);
FocusHandler fhandler =new FocusHandler();
plength.addFocusListener(fhandler);
pwidth.addFocusListener(fhandler);
pdepth.addFocusListener(fhandler);
pvolume.addFocusListener(fhandler);

// constructing the second panel
JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,1));
ButtonGroup tubtype = new ButtonGroup();
roundrButton = new JRadioButton("Round", true);
roundrButton.setActionCommand("round");
tubtype.add(roundrButton);
ovalrButton = new JRadioButton("Oval", false);
ovalrButton.setActionCommand("oval");
tubtype.add(ovalrButton);
calcButton = new JButton("Calculate Volume");
exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
hlength = new JTextField(5);
hwidth = new JTextField(5);
hdepth = new JTextField(5);
hvolume = new JTextField(5);
lengthLabel = new JLabel("Enter the tub's length (ft):");
widthLabel = new JLabel("Enter the tub's width (ft):");
depthLabel = new JLabel("Enter the tub's depth (ft):");
volumeLabel = new JLabel("The tub's volume (ft^3):");
p2.add(roundrButton);
p2.add(ovalrButton);
p2.add(lengthLabel);
p2.add(hlength);
p2.add(widthLabel);
p2.add(hwidth);
p2.add(depthLabel);
p2.add(hdepth);
p2.add(volumeLabel);
p2.add(hvolume);
p2.add(calcButton);
p2.add(exitButton);
tab.addTab( "Hot Tubs", null, p2, " Panel #1" );

calcButtonHandler2 ihandler =new calcButtonHandler2();
calcButton.addActionListener(ihandler);
exitButtonHandler ghandler =new exitButtonHandler();
exitButton.addActionListener(ghandler);
FocusHandler hhandler =new FocusHandler();
hlength.addFocusListener(hhandler);
hwidth.addFocusListener(hhandler);
hdepth.addFocusListener(hhandler);
hvolume.addFocusListener(hhandler);

// add JTabbedPane to container
getContentPane().add( tab );
setSize( 550, 500 );
setVisible( true );
} 
public class calcButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    DecimalFormat num =new DecimalFormat(",###.##");
    double sLength, sWidth, sdepth, Total;

    sLength = Double.parseDouble(plength.getText());

    sWidth = Double.parseDouble(pwidth.getText());

    sdepth = Double.parseDouble(pdepth.getText());

    if(e.getSource() == pcalcButton) {
        Total = sLength * sWidth * sdepth;
        pvolume.setText(num.format(Total));
        try{
            String value=pvolume.getText();
            File file = new File("output.txt");
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file,true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write("Length= "+sLength+", Width= "+sWidth+", Depth= "+sdepth+" so the volume of Swimming Pool is "+value);
            out.newLine();
            out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
}

public class calcButtonHandler2 implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent g) {
    DecimalFormat num =new DecimalFormat(",###.##");
    double cLength, cWidth, cdepth, Total;

    cLength = Double.parseDouble(hlength.getText());

    cWidth = Double.parseDouble(hwidth.getText());

    cdepth = Double.parseDouble(hdepth.getText());

    try
    {

        if(roundrButton.isSelected())//**roundrButton cannot be resolved
        {
            Total = Math.PI * Math.pow(cLength / 2.0, 2) * cdepth;
        }
        else
    {
            Total = Math.PI * Math.pow(cLength * cWidth, 2) * cdepth;
    }
        hvolume.setText(""+num.format(Total));
    }
 catch(Exception ex){}
}
}
}



public class exitButtonHandler implements ActionListener { //**The public type exitButtonHandler must be defined in its own file
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent g){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public class FocusHandler implements FocusListener { //**The public type FocusHandler must be defined in its own file
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    }
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    }


public static void main( String args[] )
{
    Final tabs = new Final();
    tabs.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
}

}
```

I am getting 3 errors, denoted by the `//**` next to the lines. Please help me to figure out the problems I am having.

Comment: The last two errors are rather self-explanatory, aren't they? You have to put each class into their own file. And wasn't the roundrButton issue resolved in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130300/java-initialization-question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  calcButtonHandler2 definition to accept a reference to roundButton from where it's defined.

```
public class calcButtonHandler2 implements ActionListener {

    private final JRadioButton roundrButton;

    public calcButtonHandler(JRadioButton roundrButton)
    {
        this.roundrButton= roundrButton;
    }
    ....
}
```

and pass in the reference when you create an instance of `calcButtonHandler2`

```
calcButtonHandler chandler =new calcButtonHandler(roundrButton);
```

And as for the last two error, move the class declarations to separate files as called out by the compilation error or remove the public keyword from their definitions (I would recommend the first method).

Answer (score 0):

First of all write all the classes in their separate `.java` files.

The  `JRadioButton roundrButton` is declared in the class `Final` so it cannot be accessed from another class `calcButtonHandler2` directly.

You need to use an object of the  class `Final`  to access it or you can make use of inner classes to access it.